# Azure App Service WebJob httpclient getasync request returning 500 internal server error

Tags: azure-webjobs

I have a webjob that is triggered by storage queued and makes a web api call when a new message is received.  I tested the get request in fiddler and it works, but gets 500 internal server error when the request is made via httpclient getasync within the webjob.  Can a call to a web api be made within a webjob?

Comment: I've done some tests and it looks like a webjob calling a method from the the api app that it's attached to results to 500 internal server error, but a call to other web api works.  If anyone knows why this is the case or if I'm doing something wrong, I would like to hear it.  By the way this test is pre-deployment to azure, it's done on my local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tested the get request in fiddler and it works, but gets 500 internal server error when the request is made via httpclient getasync within the webjob.

As far as I know, the 500 internal server error is thrown by your Web API server-side. Please try to wrap your code with try-catch in your Web API application and find the detailed error.

> Can a call to a web api be made within a webjob?

You could send http requests within the WebJob. Here is my code sample which could work well both on my side and Azure, you could refer to it.

**Functions.cs**

```
// This function will get triggered/executed when a new message is written 
// on an Azure Queue called queue.
public static async void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queue")] string message, TextWriter log)
{
    log.WriteLine(message);
    string requestUrl = "https://bruce-chen-001.azurewebsites.net/api/values";
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl);
    log.WriteLine("response：{0}", await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
}
```

**Result**

`response：["value1","value2"]`

Comment: thanks, I have a test method similar to what you have above and it works fine when I'm calling an app api service other than the one that I have the webjobs associated to below is my code:

Comment: public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queueName")] string message, TextWriter log)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
    var response = await client.GetAsync(new    Uri("http://localhost:1100/api/values/1"));
            using (HttpContent content = response.Content){
           if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
           {
              string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
          }
     }
}

Comment: When I moved the webjob to another api app the same code worked just fine.  Again this is local test and all urls are localhost.

Comment: Could you please try to catch the detailed error in the function of your API App, which is called within the webjob.

Comment: I've tested the web api call from the webjob, this time I restarted visual studio, and I also added try/catch in the api app method.  It worked fine this time around.  I think it's safe to assume that the error was coming from the Api App method.  Having the webjob call the web api method from the same api app that it's associated with was not the issue.  I'll mark this as the anwer.